# ArcMap get frequency of different values in text field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, text, count, frequency

I am using ArcMap 10.5. I have a large dataset of species records and ultimately want to display a breakdown of the data by different taxon group, e.g. 'bird' 'mammal' 'plant' etc., using something like a pie-chart.

I have a field in my table named  Taxon_Group which lists the taxon group for each record. I have tried using graph wizard to make a graph/chart from the data directly from this field, but it will only accept numerical values and graph the actual values of each record, rather than the count of records that fall into a particular class. I also tried to obtain the 'COUNT' statistic using the Summary Statistics tool, but again, it seems this will only accept numerical values.

The only way I have figured out how to do what I want is to use ModelBuilder, and use the Select tool to select each taxon group with a definition query, and then the Get Count tool to count the rows of the selection for each taxon group. But this is time consuming as I have many taxon groups and will probably involve some manual copy and pasting of frequency values.

Does anyone know of an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use summary statistics like this:

[image]

[image]